# How can I give different colors to each ListLinePlot combined with Show[]

Tags: graphics, color

I tried to assign different colors for each `ListLinePlot` combined with `Show`, but none of the things I tried with `PlotStyle->{}` worked for me. Why does not the following `Show[...]` give different colors to individual plots?

```
<< IGraphM`;
<< BoolEval`;

SeedRandom[13];
vLabels = {1 -> AGF, 2 -> CO12, 3 -> MA1, 4 -> MA2, 5 -> EGW, 
    6 -> CST, 7 -> WHS, 8 -> HOT, 9 -> TSC, 10 -> FIN};
legends = {AGF, CO12, MA1, MA2, EGW, CST, WHS, HOT, TSC, FIN};

make[] := RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {10, 10}];
{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5} = {make[], make[], make[], make[], make[]};

countryList = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5} ;
out[m_?MatrixQ] := {
selectBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := BoolEval[\[Theta]1 <= m < \[Theta]2];
subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
AdjacencyGraph[selectBetween[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2],
 PlotLabel -> \[Theta]1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < \[Theta]2, 
 VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels, ImagePadding -> 20, 
 ImageSize -> 150];
{"Weighted index of total number of links", 
Sum[ \[Theta]1*
  EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, Max[m]]], {\[Theta]1, 0, 
  Max[m], 0.01}]},
sectoral = {legends, 
    Sum[\[Theta]1*          
      DegreeCentrality[
       subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, Max[m]]], {\[Theta]1, 0, Max[m],
       0.01}]}\[Transpose] // Reverse // TableForm,
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{\[Theta]1, \[Theta]1*
   EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, Max[m]]]}, {\[Theta]1, 0, 
  Max[m], 0.01}], 
AxesLabel -> {"Threshold \nmultiplier: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Theta]\), \(CRI\)]\)", 
  "Weighted index \nof linkages: \
I(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(CRI\)]\))"}]
};

out[#] & /@ countryList    (* calculations for each country *)

Show[
out[#][[3]] & /@ countryList, 
AxesLabel -> {"Threshold \nmultiplier: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\
\), \(c\)]\)", 
"Weighted index \nof linkages: I(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \
\(c\)]\))"},
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[{"Costa Rica", "Morocco", "Poland", "Tunisia", 
"South Africa"}, Below], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 20}}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@countryList];
labels = {"Costa Rica", "Morocco", "Poland", "Tunisia", "South Africa"};
legend = LineLegend[colors, labels, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}];
axeslabel = {"Threshold \nmultiplier:    \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(c\)]\)", 
   "Weighted index \nof linkages: I(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\),  \(c\)]\))"};

Legended[Graphics[
  MapThread[{#, Thick, Cases[out[#2], _Line, All]} &, {colors, 
    countryList}], ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> axeslabel], Placed[legend, Below]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can post-process `Show` output to inject colors before `Line` primitives:

```
i = 1;
Legended[Show[out[#][[1, 3]] & /@ countryList, ImageSize -> Large, 
   AxesLabel -> axeslabel] /. l_Line :> {colors[[i++]], l} , 
 Placed[legend, Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: If the legend isn't necessary, one could use `MapIndexed[]`: `MapIndexed[{Directive[Thick, ColorData[97] @@ #2], Cases[out[#1], _Line, All]} &, countryList]`